# Angular2: ngFor and conditional Class

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement an 2 level navigation in Angular 2, where the first level works like an accordeon. If you click on the first level, the child elements are shown. This is done, by simple adding the css class `open` to the parent `li` element. And all of this is dynamic generated by 2 ngFor loops.

Here is what i have for now:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let row of sidebaritem; let isOpen = false;" [class.open]="isOpen">
        <a (click)="isOpen = !isOpen">{{row.title}}</a>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let child of row.children">
                <a [routerLink]="child.route">{{child.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is, that i get an "EXCEPTION: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!" error on the `(click)="isOpen = !isOpen"`part.

How can I fix this?

**SOLUTION THANKS TO PierreDuc**

The easiest way is to add an property to the `sidebaritem` class called `isOpen` and just manipulate this property:

```
class SidebarnaviItem {
    isOpen: boolean = false;

    constructor(public name?: string, public route?: any, public children?: SidebarnaviItem[]) {}
}

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let row of sidebaritem;" [class.open]="row.isOpen">
        <a (click)="row.isOpen = !row.isOpen">{{row.title}}</a>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let child of row.children">
                <a [routerLink]="child.route">{{child.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: (click) needs to refer to a function in your .ts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reassign a template variable. This can cause some unforeseen problems. A solution could be to add an `isOpen` to your `row` object:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let row of sidebaritem" [class.open]="row.isOpen">
        <a (click)="row.isOpen = !row.isOpen">{{row.title}}</a>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let child of row.children">
                <a [routerLink]="child.route">{{child.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your idea is the best one. See my complete solution above.

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare arbitrary variables in `ngFor`. Only some predefined ones can be made available this way.

You need an array in your component that allows you to store the open/close status of each row or just the index if only one row can be open at a time.
The "array" can also be an `isOpen` attribute in the `row` object.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let row of sidebaritem; let isOpen = false;" [class.open]="row.isOpen">
        <a (click)="row.isOpen = !row.isOpen">{{row.title}}</a>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let child of row.children">
                <a [routerLink]="child.route">{{child.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let row of sidebaritem; let i = index;" [class.open]="isOpen">
        <a (click)="rowStates[i].isOpen = !rowStates[i].isOpen">{{row.title}}</a>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let child of row.children">
                <a [routerLink]="child.route">{{child.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but pierreDuc was faster ;)