# ngIf in Angular 4 is not hiding the clicked <p> tag of a Row but hide all <p> of all Rows

Tags: angular

[image: Current View of my App]

**The above picture** is current view of my application add,delete are working perfectly..

[image: Final View with Working]

**The second picture** is the final view of my app which i made in **Jquery** which is **working absolutely fine**. Now I am making same app with **angular 4**, in which i am facing some problem.

[image: Angular 4 app]
**The last Picture** In angular 4 when i clicked on the edit button it hides all the

elements rather than hiding the clicked element. the below is my **html code**

```
 <div id="lists">
            <table id='mytable' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                <tr class='row' *ngFor= 'let item of list let i = index' [attr.data-index]='i' [ngStyle]="{'background-color': i%2 == '0' ? 'gray' : ''}">
                    <td class='default-field'>
                        <p class='para' *ngIf="showHide">{{i+1}}. {{item}}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="edit-field" >
                        <input type="text" class="myCl" >
                        <!-- style='display:inline-block;' -->
                    </td>
                    <td class='btns' >

                    <input type='button' value='edit' class='edit-btn' (click)='hidePara()'>

                    <input type='button' value='save' class='save-btn' > 
                    <input type='button' value='DELETE' class='delete-btn' (click)='deleterow(i)'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
```

this is my .ts file code

```
export class AppComponentComponent implements OnInit 
{
  list: string[];
  val: string;
  search:string;
  showHide: boolean;

  constructor() { 
    this.list=["Purchase a ring for my beautiful wife","get new GALAXY Note 150","Complete kevin's work ASAP","Buy 2 dozen eggs","Get milk on my way to home"];
    this.showHide = true;
  }

  ngOnInit()  {

  }
  insert=function(temp)
  {
    if(temp!="")
    {
      this.list.unshift(temp);
      this.search="";     
    }
   else
   {
     alert("Enter something");
   }
  }
  deleterow=function(p)
  {    
    if (p > -1) {
    this.list.splice(p, 1);
    }
  }

  hidePara(){
   this.showHide = !this.showHide; 
  }
}
```

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38653947/angular2-ngfor-and-conditional-class/38654044#38654044, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737692/how-to-stop-property-binding-to-every-element-in-angular-within-ngfor/46737835#46737835, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46116957/how-to-select-specific-div-on-click-in-ngfor/46116990#46116990

Comment: I am new to angular, i followed your links but couldn't understand what to do

Comment: you need a state (boolean) per element. If you have 10 items in `list` you need 10 boolean values to store the state for each one individually. If you always only want to affect one of them, you can store the index (index is shown in the linked answers and then use `*ngIf="mySelectedIdx == i"` where `mySelectedIdx is a field in you components class where you store the index of the clicked item, and `i` is from `*ngFor="let item of list; let i=index"`

Comment: please make changes in my code so i will understand, i'm facing problem